# Error creating site collection - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: 2013, site-collection

When creating a Site collection using Central admin, i am getting the error "One or more types failed to load. Please refer to the upgrade log for more details." . Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core dll version on my machine is 1.0.4632 (App Fabric 1.1).

> **Stack Trace**
>  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPSiteWssSequence ajywy
>   ERROR Exception: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   dd64ad9c-0f90-e07d-aaaa-13533e0e9e4f

Comment: SharePoint 2013?

Comment: @NkSP Yes. SharePoint 2013 Server

Comment: Did u install InfoPath? It may be the problem

Comment: @NkSP Yes. Infopath designer 2013 is installed.

Comment: I read somewhere that the Office Suite (InfoPath especially) can be the problem. But I never had that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly its asking for an appfabric dll, when checking in assembly it cant find the specified dll:

> Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core

so the first place to check is, do you have appfabric installed? look for the directory:

> c:\program files\appfabric

next if it doesnt exist install, or if the installer didnt work properly (broken setup/dlls) that download the setup installer for appfabric 1.1 :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115

.........

based on your errors, the dll you have is 1.0.4632 and the version that its referencing is 1.0.0.0 , so if you use the installer it should solve the issue!

make sure you follow this guide:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473937.aspx

**Install and configure the cache client**

> 1. Run the WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64_6.1.exe file on the Enterprise Portal server.
> 2. On the Feature Selection page, select Cache Client and clear all other options. Click Next.
>
> Cache Client
>
> The client libraries that enable you to use cache functionality in
>   your applications during development or run time. You can install this
>   component even if you are not installing the Caching Services.
>
> 3. Complete the setup wizard.
> 4. In Windows explorer, open the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ folder. Locate the web.config file and create a backup of
>      this file in a different location.
> 5. Open the web.config file.
> 6. Locate the `<configSections>`. Add the following section tag:

Copy

```
 <section name="dataCacheClient" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

> 7. Add the following AppFabric cache client tags to the web.config file after the `</configSections>`. Replace “Host_server_name” with the
>      name of the name of the server where you installed Windows Server
>      AppFabric. Replace “default” with the name specified when you executed
>      the New-Cache command.

Copy

```
<!-- velocity -->
<dataCacheClient>
    <localCache isEnabled="false" />
<hosts>
<!--List of hosts -->
<!-- Replace Host_server_name with velocity server name -->
<host name="Host_server_name" cachePort="22233" />
</hosts>
</dataCacheClient>
<Microsoft.Dynamics>
<AppFabricCaching CacheName="default" />
</Microsoft.Dynamics>
<!-- velocity -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changed the virtual directory web config of CA (Option 1 and 2 mentioned at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473937.aspx) and it worked.

Comment: no probs happy to help!