# “Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache ”

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, distributedcache, app-fabric

I am getting following error in sharepoint log:

> SharePoint Foundation   DistributedCache    air4g   Monitorable 
>   **Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache**
>       Exception: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
>       'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name:
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive,   SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encryptData)     at 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String
>   name, TimeSpan timeToLive,  SPDistributedCacheContainerType
>   containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan
>   minimumTokenExpirationWindow)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCacheInitializer.Init(Object
>   state)    '.  8230259d-fbbb-5052-7c30-    3e222f733e42

Please guide me on this issue.

Comment: please explain when are you encountering this error?

Comment: this error happens when i try to go in Sharepoint Administrator!My fronted runs well!

Comment: Taran Goel can you help me with this error? Thank you!!!

Comment: I know that the error is about the version of AppFabric version. My Central Sharepoint Admin look for the assembly Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.0.0 and I have installed the assembly Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client, Version=1.0.4656

How I can solucionate this?Pleaseeee

Comment: Why don't you run PSconfig again?

Comment: Hi Taran, I run PSConfig but it happens the error of version of assembly!

SPConfigurationDatabaseSequence ajywy ERROR Exception: **Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies**. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

What I do to update assembly?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111439/error-creating-site-collection-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-appl

Comment: thank you for your help Taran!!!

I try to install WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64_6.1.exe file on the Enterprise Portal server but I have a windows server 2012 and this version of AppFabric do not compatibility!!

How can i change the version of assembly in my installation of SP 2013?

1000 thanks!!!

Comment: did the answer there help?

Comment: No, it do not work for my problem!! I need to update my assemblies !!But i do not know how to do it!!:(!!Can you help me?

Comment: did you try reinstalling appfabric? or just run sharepoint prerequisites !